# Нету кнопки Google plugin в панеле Eclipse (toolbar)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-drive

Хочу использовать `Google Drive Api` в своем приложение. Следую этой инструкции: [Quickstart: Run a Drive App on Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)

На 3-м шаге, говорится что надо добавить `API` в приложение, надо выбрать пункт в выпадающем меню, изображение меню:

[image: изображение меню]

Суть в том, что у меня нет в `Eclips`'e этого меню. Нет кнопочки плагина от гугла. Вроде установлена последняя версия плагина, проверил обновления. А кнопки нет, и не могу добавить.   Что это может быть и как ее добавить в `Eclipse`, чтобы работать нормально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался,  просто переустановил плагин,  хотя непонятно почему после обновления кнопка не появлялась.

Answer (score 0):

1. Открой `Help->MarketPlace`
2. Там напиши "`google plugin`"
3. Выбери тот, который подходит твоему `eclipse`

Если у тебя `eclipse 4.2` то выбери 4.2